# Find difference according to pattern in large file

Tags: unix, grep, large-files, cmp

I need some help for this task:
assume we have two files while sample data like this:

```
...
N n=43222312 t=1
B a=21321 b=123123 c=213213
M a=12312 d=123

N n=43222313 t=3
M a=17712 d=121233
```

Each N is a loop number. The output varies, here we have B and M for the first line and M for the second, but we could have BBM or B for instance or even Z followed by some variables.
What I need to do is to find the first line that differs if we look only at one kind of starting letter, such as B or M. Then I'll need to output the loop number. 
I know that i could do

```
grep -w "N|B" <file1 >output1   
grep -w "N|B" <file2 >output2
cmp file1 file2
/* loop backwards to extract the n number */
```

This will work fine if the line stating with N is the same for both file. However, it isn't the case and that is why I am here asking for help... Couldn't think of a clever way to do it. Also, the file are in the size of 800MB+ so looping through the file isn't an option...
Thanks!

Sample input f1:

```
...
N n=43222312 t=1
B a=21321 b=123123 c=213213
M a=12312 d=123
...
N n=43222319 t=3
M a=17712 d=121233
```

sample input f2:

```
...
N n=43222312 t=1
B a=21321 b=123123 c=000000
M a=12312 d=123
...
N n=43222319 t=2
M a=17712 d=00000
```

output:

```
n=43222312 for case where B differs
n=43222319 for case where M differs
```

doing cmp doesn't work in this case because the line N differs in t cmp will output for me this line instead of a difference in either B or M. And a difference in the line N (here t=2 and t=3) does not mean that there will be a difference in the line B and M that follows. for instance f3:

```
...
N n=43222312 t=1
B a=21321 b=123123 c=213213
M a=12312 d=00000
...
N n=43222319 t=2
M a=17712 d=121233
```

If I'd compare f1 with this f3, I won't be able to find the different lines using cmp.

Comment: I may have been confusing in the question so here is a simpler version: I need to find the number after N n= in the case where the files differs in lines starting with B and then the other number after N n= where the files differ in lines starting with N. The goal is to compare the difference between the two number extracted. Thanks again!

Comment: please illustrate your question with sample input, required output based on that input and maybe your current output, with a brief explanation of why its not working for you. Good luck.

Comment: please note this site is for programming questions, not for other people to write programs for you. Could your problem be expressed in SQL if you loaded it into a database?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the comment. First I never dealt with SQL so that;s a dead end for me... And I will edit the question to show the inputs and outputs needed. Thanks!

Comment: I've thought of grepping them then look back for the same line but this won't work as there is the chance that there is more than one occurrence of that line...